# Symfony2, Number type returns error if the value has more than 10 digits

Tags: php, symfony

I am using number type to create form with Symfony 2.6, for example,

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mynumber', 'number', array('grouping' => true));
    }
```

If I enter more than 10 digits, such as '123456789012345', then the error "The value is not valid" returned.
Instead, if I change to 'text' type from number, it works, but I need to use grouping format. In the twig with form_row, I couldn't find how to use number_format.
I do not use any validation nor entity annotation.
Does number format allow more than 10 digits, or some validation is working behind?

Comment: This is probably because the `NumberType` can only handle numbers up to [`PHP_INT_MAX`](https://secure.php.net/manual/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max). https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php#L193